# Gradle error: Task 'clean' not found in root project

Tags: build.gradle

*ephata@Ephata MINGW64 ~/Documents/code*
`$ gradlew clean build -Pprofile=deployable --stacktrace`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'clean' not found in root project 'code'.
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are running your code from your project root folder.

The clean task is introduced by the base plugin. So you need to apply this plugin in build.gradle (app) to get the clean task and the clean task rules for cleaning up specific task outputs:

```
apply plugin:'base'
```

Comment: Thank you,
After running from root project i get a new error

Comment: > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.11.0.
     Required by:
         :message-gateway:unspecified
      > Could not resolve nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.11.0.
         > Could not get resource 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/nl/javadude/gradle/plugins/license-gradle-plugin/0.11.0/license-gradle-plugin-0.11.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/nl/javadude/gradle/plugins/license-gradle-plugin/0.11.0/license

Comment: Try updating the gradle version in gradle-wrappper.properties and other dependecies in build.gradle (app)