# Continuous Deployment throwing error using Github action

Tags: android, kotlin, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to build debug APK using github actions. But `Task 'clean' not found in root project 'My Application'.` is shown. I am not able to understand what went wrong.

I have placed android.yml like below:

[image]

My android.yml looks like this:

```
name: Android CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x ./MyApplication/gradlew

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./MyApplication/gradlew build

      - name: Build debug APK
        run: ./MyApplication/gradlew clean assembleDebug

      - name: Upload APK
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: Debug App
          path: ./MyApplication/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

EDIT: Checking tasks is a success as shown in the picture.
[image]

Settings.gradle

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
include ':library'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the root project should have the 'app' within it. It should not be the case like 'app' within another folder which caused me the issue. Here in my case, all the contents of MyApplication should be under CICDSample. Then it will build the app.

This should be the project structure.

[image]

My android.yml file looks like this:

```
name: Android CI

on:
    push:
        branches: [ main ]
    pull_request:
        branches: [ main ]

jobs:
    build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2

        - name: set up JDK 11
          uses: actions/setup-java@v2
          with:
              java-version: '11'
              distribution: 'temurin'
              cache: gradle

        - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
          run: chmod +x gradlew

        - name: Build with Gradle
          run: ./gradlew build

        - name: Checking lint
          run: ./gradlew lint

        - name: Build debug APK
          run: ./gradlew clean assembleDebug

        - name: Upload APK
          uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
          with:
              name: Debug App
              path: ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

You can download the artifact from here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check first:

- that your gradlew clean is executed [from the root folder of your project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61864798/6309),
- and that your [`settings.gradle` is *not* in your `.gitignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66117091/6309) in that same repository.
- The root folder is `MyApplication`, not `My Application`.

You can add a `./MyApplication/gradlew tasks` to see how gradle is configured.

Comment: I have applied base plugin and also settings.gradle is not present in .gitignore. Still I have the same issue. Running ./MyApplication/gradlew tasks is success only. I have edited the question with its screenshot.

Comment: @Anju Success only? It should display its configured tasks. Can you click on the `>` in front of `Task: tasks` to see if it unfolds and display more details?

Comment: > in front of Task: tasks is not clickable

Comment: @Anju OK. What is your `settings.gradle` content then?

Comment: Added the same in the question. @VonC

Comment: Suppose I am removing 'clean' and giving it like this ./MyApplication/gradlew assembleDebug, then it will throw error as Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'My Application'.

Comment: @Anju Wait... '`My Application`? Shouldn't it be `MyApplication`?

Comment: 'My Application' is automatically created when you create the app. Even if I remove the space in between issue still exists. @VonC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242256/discussion-between-vonc-and-anju).

Comment: It worked. Please check my answer.